# Remote logs in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have two machines. Machine1: airflow-webserver, airflow-scheduler. Machine2: airflow-worker on specific queue. I am using CeleryExecutor. Task on machine2 runs successfully (writing and deleting files on local drive), but in web UI on machine1 I didnt read log files.

*** Log file does not exist: /home/airflow/logs/delete_images_by_ttl/delete_images/2018-10-29T12:24:23.299741+00:00/1.log

*** Fetching from: http://localhost-int.localdomain:8793/log/delete_images_by_ttl/delete_images/2018-10-29T12:24:23.299741+00:00/1.log

*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost-int.localdomain', port=8793): Max retries exceeded with url: /log/delete_images_by_ttl/delete_images/2018-10-29T12:24:23.299741+00:00/1.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem edit your /etc/hosts. Add ip and dns-name for airflow webserver

Comment: Hi - i was facing the same issue with docker. I checked the the `etc/hosts` and found 
`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain ec2-54-226-238-125.compute-1.amazonaws.com ip-172-22-171-64.ec2.internal
`. I don't think I have a specfic DNS name and ip address. How did you change in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**HTTPConnectionPool** means webserver is not able to communicate to the worker node.

Add worker node hostname on `/etc/hosts` file

Also verify below

`base_log_folder = /home/airflow/logs/`

`sudo chmod -R 777 /home/airflow/logs/`